# warning: in c++ compare array and string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, compare

I have this  warning:

> warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

the accused is:

```
if (strchr(test[0],'E3')){
```

if I edit with

```
 if (strchr(test[0],"E1")){
```

I have this mistake:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]

considering test[0] is declared as:

```
 char *test[10];
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: 1) Be clear about what you actually *want*. 2) Read the functions' documentations to figure out which library function meets your needs.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr

Comment: So... [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr) instead ? `"E3"` is  not a `char`, so use the right function?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)?

```
std::string str(test[0]);
auto idx = str.find("E3");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function prototype:

```
const char * strchr ( const char * str, int character );
```

The strchr() function returns a pointer to the first occurrence of
the character c in the string s.

Your usage of the function prototype is wrong.

```
 if (strchr(test[0],"E1")){
```

hence, the compiler errors.

`''` will give you the ascii value of the character to be searched.

```
  char str[] = "This is a sample string";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Looking for the 's' character in \"%s\"...\n",str);
  pch=strchr(str,'s');
```

Comment: if I understand correctly I can compare a single character, not a entire string

Comment: yes...find the first occurence of a single character..You can use other functions for string comparison.